# Building temple in I Kings 6

Tags: 1-kings, temple

> "The house, while it was being built, was built of stone prepared at the quarry, **and there was neither hammer nor axe nor any iron tool heard in the house while it was being built.**" 1 Kings 6:7 NASB, [bolls.life/NASB/11/6/7](https://bolls.life/NASB/11/6/7)
>
> "So Solomon **overlaid the inside of the house with pure gold**. And he drew chains of gold across the front of the inner sanctuary, and he overlaid it with gold." 1 Kings 6:21 NASB, [bolls.life/NASB/11/6/21](https://bolls.life/NASB/11/6/21)

**How do** *"they overlaid the house within with pure gold"* **if** *"there was no hammer nor axe [nor] any tool of iron heard in the house"*?

Answer (score 4):

Gold, like lead, can be fashioned with wooden tools. Lead flashings on roofs are still, to this day, fashioned with the same wooden tools used in Roman times. I have done it myself when I did an evening class plumbing course.

They are malleable metals and can be beaten and shaped with what are called ['dressing kits'](https://www.roofingsuperstore.co.uk/browse/tools-1/bossing-tools.html) or 'bossing' kits'.

Gold leaf and pure gold metal (unalloyed) could be applied with wooden tools or the gold could be fashioned offsite and taken to the location and applied by hand and by wooden implements.

Comment: Do you think that it is just about the iron tools?

Comment: Good answer +1.